# I want to receive SMS in two different phones simultaneously

Tags: applications, sms

The messages sent to one phone meant for it only should also be received by the other phone. What is the way out?

Comment: Afraid none. Similar to calls: As soon as you pick up a call on one device, the second (listening to the same number) stops ringing. Only thing I could think of is to look for an app that synchronizes your messages – but that question would be off-topic here (you could however ask it at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)).

Comment: I'm unable to understand your question as it's written here. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: May be my question was not clear. What I wanted to know is there a way of receiving  messages by a second phone  instantly though the message was sent to another number.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. 
You'll need to use an SMS Forwarding software,
I'm not sure if you want it to be visible however...

If you would like to forward calls,

- Open Dialer
- Open Call Settings in Dialer
- Navigate to, and change the call forwarding number when unanswered.

If you want to forward SMS,

- Download an SMS Forwarding software
- Enable forwarding of incoming and outgoing sms or just incoming.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called [Forward SMS texting w/ 2phones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.mirror) which allows you to forward SMS text messages & calls from one phone to another phone.

In order to use this app you need to also use the [mysms SMS Text Messaging Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms) app.